# Filter with variable as param Django

Tags: django, orm

I have this view in Django:

```
def stutente(request):
  cog = request.GET['cognome']
  nom = request.GET['nome']
  utenti = Utente.objects.order_by('cognome')
  utenti_presenti = Utente.objects.filter(cognome="Acanfora") 
  utenti_assenti = utenti
  utenti_assenti = Utente.objects.filter(~Q(cognome="Acanfora")).order_by('cognome')  


  return render(request,"accesso/stato.html",{
      'utenti_presenti' : utenti_presenti,
      'utenti_assenti' : utenti_assenti,
  })
```

I would like to pass as parameter in the filter not the string "Acanfora" but the variable cog, that is the GET request. If I do:

```
utenti_presenti=Utente.objects.filter(cognome=cog)
```

and

```
utenti_assenti=Utente.objects.filter(~Q(cognome=cog)).order_by('cognome')
```

not function. Can you help me?

Comment: its correct only. you can also pass as parameter .. or what eles you mean ?

Comment: I could be wrong here, but I don't think you need the `~` in the second example. `utenti_assenti=Utente.objects.filter(Q(cognome=cog)).order_by('cognome')` should work. Your first example should already work, so I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: why doesn't works? raises a exception? or there's no result?

Comment: Whit cog It does not appear in the template. It turns out that present users is 0,while with cognome="Acanfora" appear in the template

Comment: Perhaps in the filter, should I put my name? Because the GET request I make is: http://127.0.0.1:8000/stutente/?nome=giuseppe&cognome=acanfora. 
But how do you make sure that nome=nom? With && not working =(

Comment: It sounds like `cog = request.GET['cognome']` isn't doing what it's supposed to. Is `cog == "Acanfora"`? Try also `cog = request.GET['cognome'].strip()` to remove whitespace.

Comment: I tried. It always comes utenti_presenti=0

Comment: acanfora is not equal Acanfora. The filter is case sensitive. Try with icontains and see if that is the problem: `utenti_presenti=Utente.objects.filter(cognome__icontains=cog)`